# Creating multiple Instances of an Object in Structure C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a structure to generate single circular object, the code is as :

```
struct point_struct {
/// Constructor
point_struct() {
    x = 0; y = 0; x0 = 0; y0 = 0; U = 0; V = 0; }
/// Elements
double x, y, x0, y0, U, V; 
};
```

/// Structure for Circular object

```
struct particle_struct {
/// Constructor
particle_struct() {
    num_nodes = particle_num_nodes;
    radius = particle_radius;
    center.x = particle_center_x;
    center.y = particle_center_y;
    center.x0 = particle_center_x;
    center.y0 = particle_center_y;
    node = new node_struct[num_nodes];
    // The initial shape of the object is set in the following.
    // For a cylinder

  for (int n = 0; n < num_nodes; ++n) {         
     node[n].x = center.x + radius * cos(2. * M_PI * (double)n / num_nodes);
        node[n].x0 = center.x + radius * cos(2. * M_PI * (double)n / num_nodes);
        node[n].y = center.y + radius * sin(2. * M_PI * (double)n / num_nodes);
        node[n].y0 = center.y + radius * sin(2. * M_PI * (double)n / num_nodes);

/// Elements
int num_nodes; // number of surface nodes
double radius; // object radius
point_struct center; // center node
point_struct *point; // list of nodes
};
```

From this code I can only generate one "circular object" but I would like to generate more may be 2, 3 .. at different locations (centers) and radii.
How can I do this?

Comment: I think you are confusing **definition** of a struct with its **instantiation**. The above code does not make any actual instance or object of **circular object**.To do that, you will have to declare it like we declare variables. E.G. `struct particle_struct array[10];` or so.

Comment: I use `particle_struct particle` in my `main()` program. Can you explain bit more @AhmedAkhtar?

Comment: Ok, so when you use `particle_struct particle;` you define an object `particle` of type `particle_struct` which is the same as defining an integer variable as `int i;` but if you want multiple variables with one name you define an array like `int a[10];` which gives you ten variables which can be used through indexing like `a[4]` accesses the fifth of the variables. Alternatively, you can declare multiple variables like `int a,b,c;` if your requirement is such. Similarly when using structs you declare multiple objects like `particle_struct a,b,c;` and arrays like `particle_struct array[12];`.

Comment: While using however, unlike an `int` variable, in a `struct` object you can also access member variables like `b.num_nodes` and for the array case `array[4].num_nodes` from the example in my previous comment.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar, Yes I understand what you want to say. I want to generate 2 or three circular objects at different locations and different sizes. How can I modify my existing structure to get my desired number of circular objects?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem as @AhmedAkhtar suggested.

Comment: OK so, I am moving the comment to an answer, please accept it for any later viewers to come and see how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to modify your existing structure for that.

You just have to declare two or three or, however much instances you want, and then set the different **location** and **sizes** in each of them separately like:

```
particle_struct particle1, particle2, particle3;
```

and then give values for `center` and `radius` and whatever else you want, one by one like:

```
particle1.center.x = 3.2;
particle1.center.y = 2.6;
particle1.radius = 12.2
```

and so on... likewise for the others:

```
particle2.center.x = 5.9;
particle2.center.y = 9.3;
particle2.radius = 7.8;
...
```

or like this:

```
particle_struct* particle = new particle_struct[SIZE];
```

or

```
particle_struct particle[SIZE];
```

and then give values of `center`  and `radius` or any characteristics like:

```
particle[0].radius = 1.0;
particle[0].center.x = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should create a new class that holds multiple `particle_struct` instances, such as :

```
class multi_particle {
     std::vector<particle_struct> many_circular_objects;
public:
     // etc
```